# Return a filtered dataframe based on target element

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and I am trying to create a function that will return a dataframe containing job opening information.
[image]

This is my code:

```
def get_available_jobs(city_state):

   data = {
       'title': [jobs_df['title'][:10]],
       'company': [jobs_df['company'][:10]],
       'salary': [jobs_df['salary'][:10]],
       'summary': [jobs_df['summary'][:10]]   }
 
   df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
   return df
```

I understand that I am missing a code to filter the data, which is the one that I can't figure out. Also, I only intend to return the first 10 rows that's why there's the [:10]. When I attempt to run the code, it is only returning 1 row, and unfiltered, which is the first row of the original dataframe. I need to return a filtered dataframe based on the city_state that will be entered.

Comment: You can create the `df` with complete data and can do filtering then using `loc`, like `df.loc[:10]`. This will return you only first 10 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering and for top 10 rows add [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
def get_available_jobs(city_state):
    cols = ['title','company','salary','summary']
    return jobs_df.loc[jobs_df['city_state'] == city_state, cols].head(10)
```